# How do return a percentage between 2 columns which is grouped by another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns.    DateRangeFields, IsOutOfTarget and AmountOfJobs.

What I need is to group results by DateRangeFields and show the percentage of jobs that are out of target for that date range.   Data shown below
I tried to create a table showing the data but Stackoverflow doesnt seem to allow that, so I created it in Dbfiddle.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae9ce68d96f0d88a3f78ad6987010f56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
Select DateRangeFields,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN IsOutOfTarget = 'True' THEN AmountOfJobs END) * 1.0 /
        SUM(AmountOfJobs)
       ) as ratio
From @MyTable t
Group By DateRangeFields;
```

Comment: TYVM  I spent ages tryng to figure out how to do this and then instead of wasting more time, came here as someone would go this is easy, just do....   :)

Comment: Hi Gordon, maybe a dumb question but why didn't you have to put an `ELSE 0` in the case statement in the case where IsOutOfTarget is not equal to 'True'?

Comment: @LadiOyeleye . . . `NULL`s are ignored in aggregation functions.  They act a lot like `0`.  The only difference is that if *all* values are `NULL`, then the result is `NULL` rather than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest way to do this but:

```
Select A.DateRangeFields, CAST(OutOfTargetJobs AS FLOAT)/CAST(OutOfTargetJobs+InTargetJobs AS FLOAT) As Percentage FROM (
Select DateRangeFields, SUM(AmountOfJobs) AS OutOfTargetJobs 
From @MyTable
Where IsOutOfTarget = 'True'
Group By DateRangeFields, IsOutOfTarget
) A
Inner Join
(
Select DateRangeFields, SUM(AmountOfJobs) AS InTargetJobs From @MyTable
Where IsOutOfTarget = 'False'
Group By DateRangeFields, IsOutOfTarget
) B on A.DateRangeFields = B.DateRangeFields;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`select sum(c1) as s_c1, sum(c2) as s_c2, divide(s_c1, s_c2) as pct from tab group by c3;`

Here `divide` is a function you can find in the official documents. I am not sure.

And it's very long for me not touching SQL.  So you konw, the statement I provided above maybe not runnable.